# How does the Xor Operator Work

Tags: c++

Could anybody please explain me how does the xor operator work in these 2 cases:

```
1. Find the kth Grey Code  k^(k>>1)
2. Find the neighboring corners of a corner in a cube:
rep (i, number_of_corners) {
            rep (j, N) {
                corners[i].sum += corners[(i ^ (1 << j))].weight;
            }
        }
```

N is the number of the dimensions of the cube.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is no executable c++ code. And your question is a little... unspecific. Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

xor is a bitwise operator with the follow truth table:

```
0 ^ 0 == 0
1 ^ 0 == 1
0 ^ 1 == 1
1 ^ 1 == 0
```

this is what happen to each and every bit in the two numbers `x`,`y` in `x ^ y`.

Comment: I know that, but I am interested to know how does xor work in finding the correct answer in the Grey Code example. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> [Exclusive-Or; From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation)
>
> **Exclusive-Or [XOR]** is a logical operation that outputs true only when both inputs differ (one is true, the other is false).
>
> *Examples:*
> 1 xor 1 = 0
> 1 xor 0 = 1
> 0 xor 1 = 1
> 0 xor 0 = 0
> 1110 xor 1001 = 0111 (this is equivalent to addition without carry)